# Can you help me identify this appliance/tool?

Tags: equipment

A friend of mine asked me to identify an appliance he saw in a picture from the Internet, and I was unable to do so.  Does anyone else know what this is?  I've highlighted it in the background of this image (it's the best picture I have):

[image: Unidentified appliance.]

It's the one with two handheld drawers on the bottom and conical hoppers up top that appear to be hinged at the bottom.  Given the rest of the items in this picture, perhaps it has something to do with coffee?  My guess is that it's a coffee roaster.

Comment: This is WALL-E's cousin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like a rotary drum coffee roaster. I can't find any pictures of one that looks exactly like it though, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the confirmation from [Satanicpuppy](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/218/satanicpuppy), I did a web search for "industrial coffee roaster" and I found [this web gallery](http://www.sweetmarias.com/Roasters-SweetMarias.php) which seems to confirm that it is a Pinhalense two-barrel propane-fired coffee roaster.  I'm going to mark Satanicpuppy's answer as correct because he/she was the first with the confirmation.